# How to create a class property in c# that is set based on computed time value but which then can be modified by a user

Tags: c#, class

Hope the question was clear.

I have a class structure in place and using it in an application already. 
User would like to however change their total time keeping the calculated time intact. Calculated time is based on ComputeHours.

How do I introduce another property that will set its value based on ComputeHours for all existing data. Then if User changes this value, the new property should reflect this adjusted time.

```
    public decimal TotalHours
    {
        get { return ComputeHours(); }
    }

    //Introducing new property
    public decimal TotalAdjusted
    {
        ???
    }
```

It's important that I get the new property to set default to existsing property value, since the Grand Total time will then be based of this.

Comment: You need a user interface.  A NumericUpDown control would be an obvious choice, use its Value property.

Answer (score 2):

this is the typical pattern:

```
private decimal _totalAdjusted;

public ThisIsMyConstructor(){
    _totalAdjusted = ComputeHours();
}

public decimal TotalAdjusted
{
    set { _totalAdjusted = value;  }
    get { return _totalAdjusted ; }
}
```

since this isn't really doing anything special with `_totalAdjusted`, you can simplify it to this:

```
public ThisIsMyConstructor(){
    TotalAdjusted = ComputeHours();
}

public decimal TotalAdjusted {get; set;}
```

---

If the result of `ComputHours` tends to change, and you want the default value to change with it, you can do this instead.

```
private decimal? _totalAdjusted == null;

public decimal TotalAdjusted
{
    set { _totalAdjusted = value;  }
    get 
    { 
        return _totalAdjusted.HasValue ? _totalAdjusted.Value : ComputeHours();  
    }
}
```

Here's an explanation of  some of the syntax there

the question mark on `decimal?` means that it's nullable.
`HasValue` is a property on a nullable object which is true when the nullable object is not null.

the `Value` property returns a non-nullable version of the nullable object.

The `?` and `:` is the ternary operator.  It essentially means if `totalAdjusted.HasValue` is `true`, then use `_totalAdjusted.Value` else use `ComputeHours()`

---

you can also just use the null coalescing operator to do the same thing.

```
return _totalAdjusted ?? ComputeHours();
```

the expression to the right of the `??` represents a default value in case `_totalAdjusted` is null

Comment: The first code is simpler with an automatically implemented property; the second code is simpler with the null-coalescing operator. Just in case you want to update them.